# laravel controller echo specific json parameter

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

my controller looks like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach($data->listings){
    echo $listing->title;
    echo $listing->times;
}
```

At the moment, I have codes that outputs the results in the view, but instead I want to retrieve and save it into database, the title and the time.

Current code gives me:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

How can this be solved?

Comment: Change your `foreach($data->listings)` to `foreach($data->listings as $listing)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to

```
foreach($data->listings as $listing){
    echo $listing->title;
    echo implode(' - ', $listing->times);
}
```

> use **var_dump()** to see the structure of array

**EDIT**
use `print_r( $listing->times)` from @美美花 answer

Comment: But some of the titles have 3 entries in array and I want to output them all for each

Answer (score 2):

```
$data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach($data->listings as $listing){
    echo $listing->title;
    print_r( $listing->times);
}
```

Comment: That outputs the whole array, I need to convert it to show times only, can you loop throught the array?

Answer (score 1):

change `foreach($data->listings)` to `foreach($data->listings as $listing)`

Comment: I get:ErrorException:  Array to string conversion

Comment: you need `json_decode($array, true)` to return as array

Comment: @morph he already do that, this error because there was an array in each child of `$data->listings`